# Override sub dependency with yarn

Tags: dependencies, package.json, yarn-v2, dependency-resolution

My project includes dependency X which in turn has subdependency Y.

When I use yarn to start my project I get the error 'Module not found: Can't resolve subdependency Y'.

However, I have another dependency called dependency Z which is a newer version of subdependency Y and which I know will work in its place. Is it possible to update my package.json so that inside of dependency X subdependency Y resolves to dependency Z instead?

This is roughly what I have in mind:

`"resolutions": { "subdependencyY": "dependencyZ" }`